# Cannot compile C++ code in Atom with g++: no such file or directory

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, atom-editor

I'm running a simple C++ program and I'm getting [an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZr0a.png) with g++. My code:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int divisor, dividend, quotient, remainder;

    cout << "Enter dividend: ";
    cin >> dividend;

    cout << "Enter divisor: ";
    cin >> divisor;

    quotient = dividend / divisor;
    remainder = dividend % divisor;

    cout << "Quotient = " << quotient << endl;
    cout << "Remainder = " << remainder;

    return 0;
}
```

The error I'm getting:

```
g++: error: /mnt/c/Users/User/Documents/assignment/hello.cpp: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Is the error message correct?  Does that file exist?

Comment: SO this is set up environment issue. The question should asked on how to set up atom environment.

Comment: The code will attempt to divide by 0 if the user feels like it.